# BFS traversal program in c using queue

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I'm studying graphs at the moment, and I'm using C. When I represent a graph with an adjacency list, I need a queue for a BFS traversal. However, I'm having some issues with the code - I'm not sure if I grasped the concept of a bfs traversal with queues well.

I pasted the commented code below, I hope it's readable. Can someone check it out, or at least provide some info on how to pull this off the right way?

program is crashing and also showing segmentation fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Queue{
    int rear;
    int front;
    int capacity;
    int* array;
};
struct adjlistnode{
    int dest;
    struct adjlistnode* next;
};
struct adjlist{
    struct adjlistnode* head;
};
struct graph{
    int V;
    struct adjlist* array;
};
int visited[100];

struct Queue* createqueue(int capacity){
    struct Queue* queue=(struct Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    queue->rear = -1;
    queue->front = -1;
queue->capacity=capacity;
queue->array=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*capacity);
return queue;
}
int isempty(struct Queue* queue){
    return(queue->front==-1 && queue->rear==-1);
}
void enqueue(struct Queue* queue,int data){
    if(isempty(queue)){
        queue->rear=0;
        queue->front=0;
        queue->array[queue->rear]=data;
        printf("%d",queue->array[queue->rear]);
        return;
    }
queue->rear=(queue->rear+1)%queue->capacity;
queue->array[queue->rear]=data;
} 
int dequeue(struct Queue* queue){
    if(isempty(queue))
        return -1;
    int temp=queue->front;
    queue->front=(queue->front+1)%queue->capacity;
    return (queue->array[temp]); 
}
int isfront(struct Queue* queue){
    return(queue->array[queue->front]);
}
/// GRAPH FUNCTIONS
struct adjlistnode* getnewnode(int dest){
    struct adjlistnode* newnode =(struct adjlistnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct adjlistnode));
    newnode->dest=dest;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    return newnode;
}
struct graph* creategraph(int V){
    struct graph* G = (struct graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct graph));
    G->V=V;
    G->array=(struct adjlist*)malloc(V*sizeof(struct adjlist));
    for(int i=0;i<V;i++){
        G->array[i].head=NULL;
    }
 return G;
}
void addedge(struct graph* G,int src ,int dest){
    struct adjlistnode* newnode=getnewnode(dest);

    newnode->next=G->array[src].head;
    G->array[src].head=newnode; 

    newnode=getnewnode(src);

    newnode->next=G->array[dest].head;
    G->array[dest].head=newnode;
}
void printgraph(struct graph* G){
    for(int i=0;i<G->V;i++){
        struct adjlistnode* temp=G->array[i].head;
        while(temp!=NULL){
            printf("%d",temp->dest);
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void bfs(struct graph* G,struct Queue* queue,int startvertex){


    enqueue(queue,startvertex);


    while(!isempty(queue)){
       int u=dequeue(queue);
       visited[u]=1;
       printf(" \n %d ",u);
       struct adjlistnode* temp=G->array[u].head;
       while(temp){
         if(visited[temp->dest]==0){
             visited[temp->dest]=1;
             enqueue(queue,temp->dest);
          }
       temp=temp->next;
       }

    }

}
void bfstraversal(struct graph* G,struct Queue *queue){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<G->V;i++)
        visited[i]=0;
    for(i=0;i<G->V;i++){
        if(!visited[i]){
            bfs(G,queue,i);
        }
    }
}
 int main(){
    struct Queue* queue=createqueue(100);


    struct graph* G=creategraph(5);
    addedge(G,1,2);
    addedge(G,1,1);
    printgraph(G);
    bfstraversal(G,queue);
  //  printf("\n%d",dequeue(queue));
}
```

Comment: This program cannot be run as is. You have not defined `enqueue` `dequeue`, `isempty` and the `main` function. Please add these functions.

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem so we can help you.

Comment: can in upload full code including main.

Comment: uploaded full code @RishikeshRaje  please help

Comment: uploaded full code @user3629249 please help

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`: 1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc    2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the parameter to `malloc()` is expected to be of type `size_t` (long unsigned int)  The conversion from `int` to `size_t` is risky and should not be relied upon

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks via a single blank line.  2) please consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  3) insert an appropriate speace inside parens, inside braces, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.  insert 2 or 3 blank lines between functions (be consistent)

Comment: next time i will keep this in mind thanks

Comment: i think i did a mistake in bfs function only so please you check only that you will get know since you are expert and i am a beginner @user3629249

Comment: Besides all the otherwise-unrelated advice, your problem is one of queue management. Eventually your front is passing your rear in your queue, yet your isempty only tests for both to be -1. If, when you dequeue, both front and rear are equal *before* the dequeue, reset them both to -1. That will probably solve your problem.

Comment: did you check my bfs function

Comment: Nope. didn't really care. I was more interested in the fault. Fix your queueing architecture and you can probably verify the rest yourself.

Comment: In the `addedge` function you are directly adding the edge to the head of the adjency list. You should check if the head is NULL and if not NULL, then traverse the list and add to the end.

Comment: please first study the kinked lists.  https://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists

Comment: While enqueuing, it's good practice to check whether the queue has already reached its capacity or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your bfs is working fine, as people have pointed out, your isEmpty() function for the queue has a flaw. It should be checking for 2 conditions,

1. No elements have been enqueued or dequeued till now. For that the condition is
   `(queue->front==-1 && queue->rear==-1)`
2. All the elements which are enqueued have been dequeued, 
   For example In the queue you have enqueued 2 , 3 then the rear=0 and front =1. Now you have dequeued 2 elements 
   which leaves the queue empty and rear=2 and front=1. This is the case where the rear exceeds the front. You have to check for the condition where the difference between front index and rear index is equal to 1.

   `((queue->capacity-(queue->front-queue->rear))%queue->capacity) == 1`

And a suggestion

While enqueuing, it's a good practice to check whether the queue has already reached its capacity or not.